# Unity 3D FPS Character Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game and I just wanted to walk around the terrain using the Standard Asset FPS First person camera character. however, when I place it on unity it gives me this errors

1.)  Assets/Standard Assets/Utility/PlatformSpecificContent.cs(15,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Build` does not exist in the namespace `UnityEditor`. Are you missing an assembly reference?

2.) Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/MobileControlRig.cs(13,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Build` does not exist in the namespace `UnityEditor`. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have no idea what they mean, can someone give me a clue?
I am using Unity 5.4 personal.

Thank you in afdvance.

Answer (score 1):

The package `Build` was introduced to the `UnityEditor` namespace in version 5.6.  You will need to change those references, or much more easily, update your Unity version to at least 5.6.